# apache .htcaccess redirect to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have problem with redirecting login page to https when i do this way:

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login https://sklep.galmet.com.pl/login [L,R=301]

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

this works when i go to `shop.abcdomain.com.pl/logn` im redirected to `https://shop.abcdomain.com.pl/logn` but all files like `.css`, `.jpeg` and so on are not loaded i think its because of this line `RewriteRule . index.php` but i don't know how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond will only apply to the first rule it comes to..  so your check for file / directory won't apply to not passing to index.php.  try this:

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login https://sklep.galmet.com.pl/login [L,R=301]

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: I guess you don't really need the first set of RewriteCond !-f ..  its pretty redundant here.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Link all your assets(css/js) file with '/' at beginning, and it should work fine.

Comment: assets are prefixed with `/`

Comment: I see. Can you please provide a part of your source code (after the page is rendered. How exactly are the assets referenced? ). I believe it has something to do with path. I had the same problem when I first used it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in to your apache .htcaccess file

**1. - options FollowSymLinks

 2. - options +Multiviews**

Comment: When i add this my site is unavilable